# How can I get differed results in javascripts using when?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm very new to Javascript (and jquery) and I have three get ajax calls: the first one eventually retrieves images (if they don't exist, that's fine), the second and third one get necessary information (if one these calls fail, we need to stop everything).

I implemented this approach with this code:

```
    // Eventually get images
    const imagesDeferred = $.Deferred();
    let images = [];
    $.ajax(...).done(function(data){
        images = data.images;
        imagesDeferred.resolve();
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Fetch Data Error: ' + errorThrown);
        console.log('Status: ' + status);
        console.dir(xhr);
        imagesDeferred.resolve();
    });

    const promises = [];

    // Fetch catalog data        
    promises.push($.ajax(...));

    // Fetch detail page
    promises.push($.ajax(...));

    promises.push(imagesDeferred.promise());

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
        // store fetched information about product
        self.detailPage.something = promises[0].responseJSON.something;
        if(images.length > 0) {
            //do something;
        }
        if (promises[1].responseJSON.something) {
            //do something            
        }
        ...
    }).fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        // used if either 2nd or 3th calls fail
    });
```

Is there a way to eliminate `images`? I thought about `imagesDeferred.resolve(data.images)`but then I don't know how to go on.

Comment: What do you mean by “eliminating images”?

Comment: @AliSoltani to get rid of it, to do the same but without using it. So, instead of defining a local list `images`, you just pass it as argument in `resolve()`or something like that. Do you understand what I mean?